# Proper script loading technique with yepnope

Tags: jquery, mobile, cookies, modernizr, yepnope

So I have built up quite a mess of scripts that need to be loaded according to three scenarios:

1. Desktop
2. Mobile
3. Mobile Full Site (Desktop version on mobile)

I had a yepnope function which tests for mobile browsers (using http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) that loaded jQuery Mobile and some other script files if true and a specifically non-mobile script file if false. However, I noticed that it forced those files to be loaded above Modernizr, meaning it loaded before jQuery.

I also have a cookie that can only be set from a mobile device if the user wants to view the desktop version. If the cookie is set, it ignores the above script.

So basically I'm just having trouble figuring out the best way to go about implementing these conditions.

- All versions require jQuery, an assortment of libraries and a main
  script file.
- The desktop version (and mobile full site) additionally requires
  jQuery UI and a non-mobile script file.
- The mobile version requires jQuery Mobile but not jQuery UI as well
  as some additional libraries and yet another specific script file for
  mobile.

I guess I should check `jQuery.browser.mobile` first and then if true check the cookie. The problem is I was having issues inserted a PHP statement into the script condition. It looks something like this:

```
if(jQuery.browser.mobile) {

    if(<?php if($_POST['dontDoMob']) { return true; } ?>) {
        // Mobile full site scripts
    } else {
        // Mobile scripts
    }

} else {
    // Desktop scripts
}
```

I imagine also that the above script would have to be run as a complete function of the yepnope loading jQuery.

Could anyone give me an idea of the correct technique for this situation?

As a side question, is it really bad practice to load jQuery Mobile and jQuery UI together? Is the former meant to replicate the latter (in some ways) on mobile platforms? Is it just a waste time to load jQuery UI?

**UPDATE (see comments below):**

I've settled on using the following technique to detect four types of devices/device states; desktop, phone, tablet and desktop site on a phone (phonefull). Uses the great [Mobile Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/)
 class.

```
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';

$detect    = new Mobile_Detect;
$desktop   = false;
$phone     = false;
$tablet    = false;
$phonefull = false;
$class     = '';

if( $detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet() ) {
    if($_COOKIE['dontDoMob']) {
        $phonefull = true;
        $class = 'phonefull';
    } else {
        $phone = true;
        $class = 'phone';
    }
} else if( $detect->isTablet() ) {
    $tablet = true;
    $class = 'tablet';
} else {
    $desktop = true;
    $class = 'desktop';
}

?>
```

The `class` variable is echoed into the `<body>` tag for easy use in CSS and JavaScript.

Then to use the device variables, simply do a normal PHP if statement:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<?php if($phone) { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css">
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: The proper way to use yepnope is to not use yepnope.

Comment: @adeneo do you have a useful alternative for loading different scripts in a mobile browser to in a desktop browser?

Comment: @Racheet See my update in the post.